# Are there examples of XOR of OWF still being OWF?

Tags: one-way-function

I am trying to prove that given two OWF $f$ and $g$ the function $h$ given as:

$$\text{h}(x)=(\text{f}(x),\text{g}(x))$$

is not always OWF. As a counter example I am considering $\text{f}(x) = \text{g}(x) \oplus x$.

For this to work I need to find an example of $\text{f}$ and $\text{g}$ still being OWF. I know that I can find examples of this not being the case, but are there examples of $\text{f}$ and $\text{g}$ being OWF and $\text{f}(x) = \text{g}(x) \oplus x$ holding true?

Comment: Don't you mean $\text{f}(x) = \text{g}(x) \oplus x$? Currently there is only a function identifier and no parameter for $g$...

Comment: It appears that you introduced that error in you edit, when you (for unclear reasons) swapped $f$ and $g$.

Comment: yes I meant g(x), I corrected it now.

Comment: If the random oracle model is acceptable: If $H$ is a random oracle, then it's not hard to show that $H(x)\oplus x$ is a OWF.

Comment: It seems very likely that such a OWF exists but I can't see how to prove it either right now. Are you set on this particular counterexample? There are definitely easier ones.

Comment: @Maeher no, any other way to prove the original problem would also do for this, but I was just curious since I found f()=g()⊕ as a possible solution.

Comment: @Mikero very interesting, I am reading about the random oracle now, would you mind elaborating a bit more about how such a proof would look like?